# read and write a file in vbscript by escaping special characters

Tags: string, vbscript

I want to copy a text file to another by escaping the special characters in the text and enclosing the output withing double quotes

For example. consider the input file to be:

```
ABC"hi%"
bcd
```

i want the output to be

```
"ABC" + "" + "hi%" + "" +vbCRLF + "bcd"
```

in a single line.
the script should dynamically add carriage return and linefeed at the end of each line in the input text.

any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I have an idea of how to approach, since im new to vbscript im not able to get the code to work.

Comment: (1) example does not demonstrate escaping (2) VBScript's concatenation operator is `&` (3) vbCrLf can't be part of a single line

Comment: what i was thinking was to get the file by ReadLine and loop through each, check for special char and replace, finally add vbCRLF at the end.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner yes i havent properly escaped special char. the main purpose is to convert the text in to a single line enclosed in double quotes.
since the original text contains quotes i want that to be escaped so that it doesnt interfere with the opening and closing quotes.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner He probably wants to write a text parser that would produce a VBScript expression to (re)generate the input text. That topic is *way* too broad for an answer on SO, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a series of `Replace()` statements.

```
s = objTextStream.ReadAll()

s = Replace(s, """", """""")
s = Replace(s, vbTab, """ & vbTab & """)
s = Replace(s, vbCrLF, """ & vbCrLf & """)
.... 

' Add quotes around the whole string
s = """" & s & """"
```

Because of the need to concatenate, however, you could end up with some empty strings in the final result. For example, if you had consecutive tabs, your output string would look something like this:

```
"some text" & vbTab & "" & vbTab & "" & vbCrLf & "Line2"
```

So you may have to do one final `Replace()` to get rid of those:

```
s = Replace(s, "& """" &", "&")
```

Comment: Thanks , will try and let you know.